# Feedback on Haskell FFI

Tags: haskell, f#, ffi

I am new to functional programming (a C++ / C# programmer mostly) and I am about to start a new project. There are no strict deadlines, and at this point there are no restrictions on which technologies can be used.

The core of the project  is to parse (relatively) large CSV files and to populate Excel and Word templates. I am considering two approaches, Qt/C++ - Haskell doing the CSV parsing, calculations and such, and C# for UI with F# doing the heavy lifting. I want to start with C++/ Haskell since it is more challenging.

My primary concerns are FFI and state in Haskell.
How robust is Haskell FFI for passing large arrays of structures and C callbacks?
Do I use the State monad to retain the large data set in memory between the function calls into the Haskell DLL? I am new to Haskell :)

Comment: Why are you wanting to use Haskell?  That just seems to be increasing the complexity of your system for no reason (not to say it has no uses, simply that in this case there seems to be no clear case).

Comment: I spent the last 2-3 month reading 2 Haskell books and I want to put this knowledge to use. This is a side project.

Comment: 10 years ago the most viable choice would be to COM script Excel and Word with Haskell + GreenCard. Unfortunately GreenCard has bit-rotted as its creators moved on, I know people have subsequently resurrected it but I'm not sure how user-friendly it is at the moment. As Excel can be scripted from .Net, these days I'd think F# has a considerable head-start on Haskell. However a possible route for Haskell would concentrate on transforming CSV -> CSV and use a little F# or even VBA for the final step.

Comment: That I am not concerned about too much, Qt can handle MS office fairly well.

Answer (score 11):

> How robust is Haskell FFI for passing large arrays of structures?

Everything must be marshalled/unmarshalled at the language barrier. It's common to make large data structures be opaque to one language or the other. That is, if there's a large C data structure, simply keep a pointer to it in Haskell-land and import C functions that do the operations you need; likewise, if there's a large Haskell data structure, expose the Haskell functions that munge it to C-land.

> How robust is Haskell FFI for C callbacks?

It is easy and common to turn Haskell closures into C-style function pointers.

> Do I use the State monad to retain the large data set in memory between the function calls into the Haskell DLL?

This depends a lot on the API you design. In many cases (e.g. most UI libraries) this is not really feasible, because the main loop is in C, not Haskell; one instead uses `IORef` or similar.

That said: if this is your first Haskell project, I strongly recommend avoiding manual FFI efforts, especially making an attempt to mix Haskell and C++ via the FFI. There's plenty of difficult stuff to get accustomed to without throwing that into the mix. If the only thing you were planning to use it for was UI, then take advantage of others' hard work: there are Haskell bindings to the biggest UI toolkits available on Hackage.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I was thinking of doing all of the UI in Qt (C++), Haskell would be for parsing CSV, calculations and such.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I was thinking of doing all of the UI in Qt (C++), Haskell would be for parsing CSV, calculations and such. I wanted to say that I am well familiar with Qt, and it has a decent UI designed and IDE. I looked at wxHaskell and gtkhs and it looks like it will involve hand coding of the UI. Plus I need Qt to handle Excel and Word which it can do fairly well.

Comment: @MUXCAH There are Haskell bindings to Qt.

Answer (score 10):

Learning Haskell is a great way to become a good functional programmer as it teaches you how to write code in a purely functional way - which is something that other functional languages emphasize too, but they do not force you to do it.

That said, if you want to interoperate with something like Excel (which is inherently a mutable imperative API), then using a language that does not force you to be pure might be an easier way to approach the problem.

Most of the people writing code for Excel these days are using .NET and so the .NET libraries for Excel (which work nicely from F#) are much more advanced than what you'd get in any other platform.

You might want to look at the following libraries before deciding:

- [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) is a very well documented library, wrapping all of the Office APIs in a (fairly) easy to use .NET API which you can use from F# without any impedance mismatch.
- [Csv Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) which is a part of F# Data is not just a CSV parser, but it also infers the type based on your CSV file and gives you a typed access to the CSV data structures.
- If you want to do some data analysis, then [Deedle](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/) is an open-source data analytics library for F# that has been developed by BlueMountain Capital and is very well tested - and has really simple API for doing basic data analysis on reasonably sized (but fairly big) data sets (you should be fine if it fits in 2GB)

Sounds like for the kind of project you are describing, you can really get a lot just by using the .NET/Mono libraries and F#-specific libraries that are already out there - and being on the same runtime, you do not have to worry about any FFI.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (and Haskell doesn't "force you to be pure"; it just segregates non-pure code clearly in the type system).

Comment: You're right. I'm not trying to answer the question, but to give a useful guidance. Using Haskell for FFI with Excel sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: I guess that should be a comment then - the question is pretty clear about what it's asking for.

Comment: "I am new to" might suggest that guidance can be of some use though

Comment: "Don't do this" is often the best answer. If someone asks how to jump off a cliff, we are not obliged to push them.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. After some research I decided to implement the project in C# / F#. F# seems to be a better tool for this particular job.

Comment: I agree it's the right advice unless you're really keen to learn a lot about random bits of Haskell FFI, it just belongs in a comment.